# Google Maps Javascript Api. Map markers infoWindow display

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

i have wrote a script to display multiple map markers with search via zip code, or address also to display the distance between the multiple markers and the given location from user but.. i want to display infoWindow with some content that i will write to each one of the markers...Can anyone help me??

The script goes like this :

```
 var features = [
      {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.089374, 23.809245),
        type: 'info'

      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.865212, 23.744748),
        type: 'info'
      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.997172, 23.693429),
        type: 'info'
      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.934769, 23.879542),
        type: 'info'
      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.003720, 23.886767),
        type: 'info'
      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.027083, 23.850951),
        type: 'info'
      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.944077, 23.661457),
        type: 'info'
      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.017348, 23.796585),
        type: 'info'
      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.955754, 23.677229),
        type: 'info'
      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.971261, 23.756350),
        type: 'info'
      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.990022, 23.720621),
        type: 'info'
      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.050031, 23.752440),
        type: 'info'
      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.464754,23.615317),
        type: 'info'
      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.943692, 23.748214),
        type: 'info'
      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(39.544696, 21.775843),
        type: 'info'
      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.668344, 22.889161),
        type: 'info'
      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.662039, 22.911951),
        type: 'info'
      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.573629, 23.025070),
        type: 'info'
      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.303271, 21.804128),
        type: 'info'
      }

    ];



    // edw oi kaloi oi markers.
    features.forEach(function(feature) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: feature.position,
        icon: icons[feature.type].icon,

        map: map
      });



    });
```

Comment: There aren't any [InfoWindows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) in the posted code.

Comment: yes, cause no matter how much i tried to insert InfoWindows they are not working properly. as you can see the var features are my markers and even if i put any piece of code for an infowindow does not show up, or i can see the window when i click but its empty... (forgive me if i did not make it clear cause im new to this)

Comment: Can you show what your code looks like when you attempt to insert the info window? Then we can tell you what you've done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this! I am not an expert though as per your question I am sharing the way I think I would have done it.

Please note I haven't tested the code so please do check and if there is any problem let me know.

```
       var markers = [
       {
           lat: 38.089374, 
           lng: 23.809245,
           type: 'info'

       }, {
           lat: 40.668344,
           lng: 22.889161,
           type: 'info'
       }, {
           lat: 40.573629, 
           lng: 21.804128,
           type: 'info'
       }];
       var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
       var mapOptions = { 
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
         mapTypeControl: false,
         fullscreenControl: false,
         streetViewControl: false,
         zoomControl: true,
       };
       var mapDiv = document.getElementById('mapdiv');
       var map =  new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);
       var location;
       if( markers.length > 0 ){
          for( var i=0; i<markers.length; i++ ){
              location = new google.maps.LatLng( markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng 
       );
       bounds.extend( location );
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: location,
                      map: map,
                      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                  });
        var content = '<div class="someclass">Your content goes here.</div>';
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth:350});

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover' ,(function(marker,content,infowindow) {
              return function() {
                     infowindow.setContent(content);
                     infowindow.open(map, marker);
              };
        }) (marker,content,infowindow));
    }
}
```

And finally, if it helps you to solve your problem don't forget to accept it.

Comment: thank you very much for this!! It works indeed!! but i need also to display the content for each marker differently for example the 1st marker has the phrase "Hello world" in his infowindow, the 2nd one has the phrase "Hello flowers" etc. If you have the solution to this i would be very thankfull to you..but Thank you again for the 1st solution :)